If both RA and DHCPv6 provide DNS servers, which one would devices use?
I use a home router that also has a DNS server that forwards to the ISP DNS servers and caches them. But I don't want to use ISP DNS servers, so I configured the router's DHCP and DHCPv6 server to offer external DNS servers addresses. But as I noticed, Router Advertisement also offer itself as a DNS server and I can't change that.
Currently, I see my PC use the DNS server offered by DHCP, but would it still in the future?

As far as I know Windows, MacOS and Linux ignore the RA completely and solely rely on the DHCP information to configure their own IP interfaces. Including DNS.
(Some routing software run as an add-on on any such OS may use RA, but the OS itself doesn't.)
Obviously we can't predict the future. Best we can do is make an educated guess.
Since there is no real need for a consumer OS to make use of RA if there is DHCP and given the ubiquitous use of DHCP these days I don't think this is going to change anytime soon.

That's not true – Windows got built-in RDNSS support as of 10.1703, Linux with NetworkManager will automatically use it as of 0.9 or so, etc. – and DHCPv6 is by no means ubiquitous; there are probably more IPv6 networks that don't have it than networks which do.

@grawity_u1686 I think we BOTH have a point. I do know that the support is there and recent Windows/Linux/MacOS will use it for Ipv6 DNS if there is no DHCPv6 available, but for almost all consumer-setups (if they have IPv6) there is a local ISP router involved that acts as IPv6  firewall (hopefully) and provides DHCPv6. In those cases RA never comes into play.
Non consumer networks are a different story altogether, but this SE site is predominantly aimed at consumer setups. I gave my answer in that vein. Could have been more precise, I agree.

Actually no. At least on Fedora, which is using systemd-resolved, it accepts both RA and DHCP provided DNS servers, then it randomly pick one of them. I noticed it's using the RA DNS on my machine today.
